# HQL left join return null

Tags: hibernate

When trying to request MySQL database using HQL I got always null on unique result.

```
   select _it
     from com.abgc.fab.entities.FabFmenuentry _it
left join _it.entitytype as a1_entitytype
    where a1_entitytype.ref = :p1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try left join fetch instead of left join and remove select _it

Comment: thanks, it worked for me, the problem with lazy fetch